# Implementation approach for forgot password in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a main application that sits within authorised login. All routes are sitting within a Route Guard. I now need to implement a forgot password component that should sit outside of the login. I have 2 requirements.

1. The forgot password page should have the url http://

   It should be excluded from the route guard checks.

What would be the best approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The router checks whether the path you wish to navigate to matches the URL you are going to in the order in which they are listed in your array of routes, so you can simply put the forgotPassword page at the top of your routes, then put a `path: ''` that will match every other url below that.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'forgotPassword',
    component: ForgotPasswordComponent
},
{
    path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
        // All other components
    ]
}
];
```